# Can someone explain memory management

Tags: iphone, xcode

OK, so I am halfway through developing an iPhone app and I keep stumbling when it comes to memory management.

I have tried a number of times to understand this with very limited success. I consider myself to be above average intelligence, but this stuff just eludes me, despite repeated searches and reading of Apple documentation

Lets say I have a picker that I am creating - so the code goes

```
UIPickerView *patientPicker = [[[UIPickerView alloc] init]retain];
//more code here
[self.view addSubView:patientPicker];
```

So then I do a couple of different things with my picker.

The picker only appears when a segmented control button is pressed. The segmented control dictates which array of data is used to populate the picker.

However, when I change segmented control, I find that it displays a new picker on top of the old picker, rather than changes the data in the current picker.

i.e. segmented control is patient age or weight. If age is selected a picker of ages appears, and the same if weight is selected the picker of weight appears. However if one of the pickers is already present, then clicking on the alternate segment doesn't change the data, it just adds another picker onto the view.

My problem comes when I try and hide the picker as the old picker is still underneath, and I can't hide the old one.

So when I click a button to remove the picker, the old picker is still present underneath.

I have tried

```
[patientPicker removeFromSuperView];
```

but when I try and rebuild my picker I am advised that patient Picker has been deallocated???

The same goes for

```
[patientPicker release];
```

I know that someone would be able to tell me the simple answer, but what I really want is a really simple/dumbed down explanation of memory management so that I don't have to ask again.

Pretend I am 7 years old!

Thanks

Bob

Comment: You need to do one of two things:  1) Buy a good book on Objective-C/iOS programming and study the chapter on memory management.  2) Stick exclusively to using the ARC (automatic reference counting) environment in iOS 5/Xcode 4.

Comment: (And before you do either of those you need to have a good fundamental understanding of OO.  Many people can't get the concept that you can have multiple different objects of the same class, and storing a value in one does not make that value magically appear in another.)

Comment: @Hot Licks: ARC support is available from iOS 4.3 and newer.

Comment: @WolfgangSchreurs -- True, but why confuse the OP with trivia?

Comment: @Hot Licks: Personally I think this is very important to notice, even though it's not related to the issue. If a developer wants to target a large audience, the developer should know it's quite safe to use ARC. I'm sure many developers wouldn't consider using ARC yet if it only supported iOS 5.

Comment: @WolfgangSchreurs -- But the OP hardly understands what an object is.  He's a long way from being able to "target a large audience".  Crawl before you walk.

Comment: Hmmm, Thanks for your comments - rather than directing me to a book, can you recommend a website that will take me through step by step? By the way, I tried using the ARC, but I just kept getting the bits of code I did understand failing all over the place because I was trying to over-release stuff.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIPickerView *patientPicker = [[[UIPickerView alloc] init] retain];
```

Here you **don't/shouldn't** do a `retain`.  The `init` call already implies that the caller is responsible for the create object (in other words, `init` has a `retain` implied).  You need a `release` for every `init` and `retain`.

Answer (score 0):

I reckon that you doing an `alloc/init` each time the segmented control changes selection. What you can do is, In the `vieDidLoad`, do this:

```
UIPickerView *patientPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init;
//more code here
[self.view addSubView:patientPicker];
patientPicker.hidden = YES;
[patientPicker release];
```

When the selection is made on segment control, set the hidden property of the picker to `NO` and set the `datasource` according to the selection

Comment: Clever - I will definitely try that!! I reckon that will fix it all for me

Answer (score 0):

this sounds like a job for a tool... yes! hit Build and Analyze and remove every issue =) but understand *why* the static analyzer flags your program, and understand that there's quite a bit it can catch, yet quite a bit that it can't prove is a reference count imbalance and will not flag these. then run with leaks instrument and fix all issues, etc. and if you run into deallocated instances, run zombies instrument and fix all issues.

anyways, there's more to it! here are some points to your code.

```
UIPickerView *patientPicker
         = [[[UIPickerView alloc] init]retain]; // << do not retain here. alloc 
                                          // returns an object you must release

[self.view addSubView:patientPicker]; // << self.view will retain its subviews.
                                      // ok, that makes sense that the view
                                      // would want to hold onto a reference to
                                      // ensure the view is not destroyed
                                      // while it's still a subview.

[patientPicker removeFromSuperView]; << the superview will release its subview 

[patientPicker release]; << your life will be easier if you use the accessors
```

when you're dealing with reference counting, you need to hold a reference to use an object. so, let's take autorelease pools out of the equation. using autorelease only when needed will help you learn, and make some of your issues local to the callsite -- avoid calling autorelease where possible while you are learning.

```
NSString * a = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; // << I hold 1 reference
[a length]; // ok
[a retain]; // << I hold 2 references
[a release]; // << I hold 1 reference
[a release]; // << I hold 0 references
[a length]; // expect bad things
```

now let's illustrate autorelease pools:

```
NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSString * a = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; // << I hold 1 reference
[a length]; // ok
[a retain]; // << I hold 2 references
[a release]; // << I hold 1 reference
[a autorelease]; // << add a to pool. when pool is destroyed a release message will be sent to a
[a length]; // ok. a is still alive. its release message is deferred until the pool is destroyed
[pool release]; // pool's reference count has reached zero. pool will call [a release]. pool will be destroyed. 
[a length]; // expect bad things
```

Comment: Interesting Justin - is there a way to NSlog the number of references?  Thanks for an informative post

Comment: @Bob There is. It's called Instruments. First stop: Zombies Instrument  -- remove any zombies Next: Leaks -- remove all the leaks you can. To get the reference count operations: go to the Allocations Instrument (which Leaks and Zombies add for you) - click the 'i'. click "Record reference counts". Record something. Stop. View Allocations as "Object List". Locate and select the allocation. Click the arrow near its address. cmd+E to display the extended info. Instruments has recorded the callstack for all ref count ops.

Comment: Apple has an guide on memory management. Understanding that should be your starting point. Have you read it?

Answer (score 0):

Two rules of memory management:

- If you `new`, `alloc init`, `retain`, or `copy` (N.A.R.C.) an object, you have to release it.
- When the name of a method starts with any of those words, it means it's being created for the caller, who has the responsibility to `release` the object when he is done with it. Otherwise the method returned is not owned by the caller, and he has to indicate he wants to keep it calling `retain` on the object.

Note that the first rule results in the second. A method creates an object (therefore it is responsible for releasing it) but if the outcome of the method (the returned object) survives the execution of the method (so it can be handed to the caller) all the method can do is autorelease the object. An autorelease adds the object to the autorelease pool, which will release the object at some point in the future.

Example:

```
[[MyObject new]; // 1)
[NSString initWithFormat:@"%d",1]; // 2)
[NSString string]; // 3)
```

1) Name contains new, so it will need release.
2) Name contains init, so it will need release.
3) Name doesn't contain any of the NARC words so you know it returns an autoreleased object. This means you need to retain it if you intend to keep it, and if you do, you will need to release it later. Otherwise just use it and forget about it.

Couple of tips:

- Try to retain/release symmetrically so you don't lose track of what to release and where. Example: if you retained on init, then release on dealloc. Same for viewDidLoad/viewDidUnload.
- If you can choose, don't abuse autorelease when memory is a concern so you recover your memory as soon as possible. Abusing autorelease is also a sign you don't understand memory management.

Your example (same thing Justin told you):

```
UIPickerView *patientPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc] init]; // 1)
[self.view addSubView:patientPicker]; // 2)
[patientPicker release]; // 3)
```

1) We call alloc init so you know this object will need release once you are done with it.
2) addSubView calls retain internally. Why? When you receive an object and you intend to keep it, you express that intention calling retain, which also gives you the responsibility of releasing it. When a UIView is released, its implementation also releases its subviews to balance the retain done before by addSubView.
3) We won't be using it anymore so we call release. Now self.view is the owner of the object.

As an exercise, try to implement your own setter and getter for a variable and run Build and Analyze to see what Xcode thinks about it.

Comment: Ok, I kind of get what you are saying, especially the NARC bit. But what about if instead of UIPickerView *pickerView =[[UIPickerView alloc]init];etc I placed in the .h file @property (non atomic, retain) UIPickerView *patientPicker and then wrote pickerView =[[UIPickerView alloc]init]; how would that change things (if it does at all?)

Comment: `UIPickerView *pickerView =[[UIPickerView alloc]init]; self.pickerView = pickerView; [pickerView release]; -(void)dealloc{ [pickerView release]; [super dealloc]; }`. That's 1) alloc+init, 2) retain from the @property, 3) release of the object (now it belongs to the property, you don't need it). And when the class is deallocated 4) the dealloc releases the ivars and you are done. The retain/release pairs are 1,3 and 2,4.

Comment: If you also do `[self.view addSubView:picker]`, that causes another retain, and then when the view is released, it will release all its subviews balanced the retain in addSubView. I don't know why you also want the picker as an ivar after setting a UIPickerViewDelegate, but whatever, it's fine for memory management.

Answer (score 0):

Focus on Ownership, if you have ownership; you have to `release` object. If you don't have ownership don't dare to `release` it.

---

`id myObject;`
`myObject = [abc retain]` => you are the owner

`myObject = [[abc alloc] init]` => you are the owner

`myObject = [abc copy]` => you are the owner

---

`myObject = [[[abc alloc] init] autorelease]` => you are not the owner 
(everywhere you put `autorelease` you loose the ownership)

`myObject = [abc xxxWithYYY]` => you are not owner 
(as a convention, a method returning object always give an `autorelease` object)

---

There will be some more similar conventions where you can identify OWNERSHIP; I just jotted down what I can recall now.